# Force rails to read attribute instead association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, serialization, associations

I have a bit of a weird issue. I'm trying to refactor some code and currently I've a model set up as:

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :states, Array
end
```

And in above the serialized array `state` stores the id of different states.

I want to transfer this to a `join table` which would hold the id of `Level` and `State` so I updated the model as follows:

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :levels_states, inverse_of: :level
  has_many :states, through: :levels_states
  serialize :states, Array
end
```

Now the issue is that I can't transfer the existing data from column `states` because Rails is looking for the association `states` rather than the serialized array. I want to create a migration to transfer the SQL data but I've been unable to access the `states` array.

Comment: I would suggest you to remove/rename the relation `has_many :states, through: :levels_states`, create and run your migration to create `levels_states` records, deploy, and only then remove the `states` attribute + setup `states` through relation.

Comment: But if you really want to do both at the same time, you could try using `read_attribute :states` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/read_attribute)

Comment: @MrYoshiji it seems like your I'll have to follow your initial suggestion to solve this issue. Thank You!